# Crossing analog traces with power trace

Tags: layout, trace

I have a two layer board. Analog signals on the top layer and power traces on the bottom layer. Should they cross each other at 90 degrees? How bad would it be when the bottom trace and the top trace "lay on top each of other"?

My analog signal has a bandwidth of around 1MHz

Comment: This is hugely dependent on how noisy your power is and how sensitive your analog signals are. In some cases it will be absolutely fine, in others it will utterly destroy your signal.  To help get a relevant answer, you can update your post with more details - such as the bandwidth and acceptable noise for your analog signal. Or if you're not sure what those are, then the type of signal and what is is coming from and going to.

Comment: Its a signal with 1MHz bandwidth coming from an opamp going to another opamp

Comment: So the first opamp has a low impedance output, and the second has a high impedance input. That will help. What level of noise can you tolerate in the signal? Also, what is the power trace like? From a switch mode supply or linear regulator? And do all the loads have decoupling capacitors?

Comment: From a LDO, yes all loads have decoupling caps. I don't really know about the noise levels.

Comment: What is the amplitude of the 1 MHz BW signal?

Comment: A good cross-talk analysis tool will tell you how much coupling you have between signals and between signal and power traces.  Then based on the particulars of your design, you can see how much of a problem you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It'll almost certainly be fine**

Based on the comments, the analog signal is running from one opamp to the next. This means it has a low impedance source, so it will be quite robust.

It also seems the power supply comes from a linear regulator, which will tend to produce a low-noise power supply. As long as the loads are well decoupled, they won't introduce much noise either, so the power supply trace won't be carrying much noise.

Without a target to hit, it's impossible to say whether the noise it brings in will be too much. But based on the above, it will be very small, and there are likely to be other noise sources in the system which are (much) larger.

Answer (score 1):

Power supply wiring carries voltage (nearly unchanging) and current (which
might have surges/spikes at relatively high frequency).

So, capacitive coupling from signal to DC power wiring is usually not troublesome; after all, the power wiring voltage is nearly unchanging and only dV/dt terms show
up in the signal from a capacitive sneak path.   The current, however, may
couple from one wire path to another (parallel) wire path, and may have high
frequency character because currents are typically UN-regulated, not kept
constant.   Two parallel wires, one sensitive and one current-carrying from
a power supply, DO couple, in transformer fashion.

There are a number of ways to combat this; crossing such wires at right angles
is one, and interposing a ground plane between them (equivalent to a shorted
secondary winding on the accidental transformer) is another.   A third is
twisted-pair wiring for either the power or the signal (or both).   Many
accidental signal-pickup possibilities can be treated with ferrite chokes,
which (like the ground plane) force a pair of conductors to have symmetric
and opposite high frequency currents.